# Date Formulas to update a file path in Batch File

Tags: microsoft-excel, batch, batch-file

I am trying to write a batch file to convert a set of excel files from .xls to .xlsx for a monthly report that I have.

This is what I currently have:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office14\excelcnv.exe" -oice "H:\File Path\2018\Support\03 March\Other\03 Export.xls" "H:\File Path\2018\Support\03 March\Other\03 Export.xlsx"
```

I would like to be able to run this without having to change the month in the file path, which looks something like this:

```
H:\File Path\2018\Support\03 March\Other
```

I would like to make it so that when I run this next month, it will automatically put "04 April" where 03 March is. It would also be great if I could populate the 2018 in the file path as well. Is this possible for a batch file?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
:: Q:\Test\2018\04\12\SU1313056.cmd
@Echo off&SetLocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion

:: Get date in a locale/user-settings independent format
for /f "tokens=1-3 delims=.+-" %%A in (
  'wmic os get LocalDateTime^|findstr ^^[0-9]'
    ) do Set _DT=%%A
Set "yy=%_DT:~0,4%"&Set "MM=%_DT:~4,2%"&Set "dd=%_DT:~6,2%"

:: Build MonthName[01..12] array
Set i=100&Set "MonthName= January February March April May June July August September October November December"
Set "MonthName=%MonthName: ="&Set /a i+=1&Set "MonthName[!i:~-2!]=%"
:: Set MonthName

Set "Excel=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office14\excelcnv.exe"
Set "Src=H:\File Path\%yy%\Support\%MM% !MonthName[%MM%]!\Other\%MM% Export.xls"
Set "Dst=%Src%x"

:: Show command
Echo "%Excel%"  -oice^^
Echo   "%Src%" ^^
Echo   "%Dst%"

If Not exist "%Excel%" (Echo Can't find "%Excel%" & Pause & Exit /B 1)
If Not exist "%Src%"   (Echo Can't find "%Src%"   & Pause & Exit /B 1)

::DoIt
"%Excel%" -oice "%Src%" "%Dst%"
```

Sample output:

> "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office14\excelcnv.exe"  -oice^
>     "H:\File Path\2018\Support\04 April\Other\04 Export.xls" ^
>     "H:\File Path\2018\Support\04 April\Other\04 Export.xlsx"
>   Can't find "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office14\excelcnv.exe"
>   Can't find "H:\File Path\2018\Support\04 April\Other\04 Export.xls"

Comment: Thank you! This works for me! Is it possible to get it to show the prior month? So if it's April now, we would be running the March reports. Thanks!